# Show that any nonzero free $F[x]$-module $V$ is an infinite dimensional vector space over $F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

**The Problem**: Show that any nonzero free $F[x]$-module $V$ is an infinite dimensional vector space over $F$.

**My Attempt**: I understand that $V$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of $F[x]$, but that did not seem to help. Hence I, BWOC, supposed that $V$ IS a finite dimensional vector space over $F$. Then there exists a basis $\mathcal{B}=\{v_1,\dots, v_n\}$ for $V$. Suppose $v\in V$, then $v=r_1v_1+\dots+r_nv_n$, where $r_i\in F$. **Screeching Halt**.

**My Question**: Obviously I want to show that $v=f_1(x)v_1+\dots+f_n(x)v_n$ with $f_i(x)\in F[x]$ such that NOT all $f_i(x)=r_i$, then we'd have a contradiction; but I failed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**: This problem turns out to be a bit more involved than I have anticipated, so I'll add more background here. $F$ is a field, $T: V\to V$ is a linear transformation. Then every $p(x)=a_nx^n+\dots+a_1x+a_0\in F[x]$ acts on $v\in V$ as follows: $p(x)v=a_nT^n(v)+\dots+a_1T(v)+a_0v$. With this action, $V$ is called an $F[x]$-module.

Comment: Consider the elements $v, xv, x^2v, \dotsc$, and show that they are linearly independent over $F$ (for $v \neq 0$).

Comment: If, as you say in your edit, a priori $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $F$, then certainly it cannot be infinite dimensional over $F$.

Comment: @Servaes Good point! Fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, $V$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of $F[x]$. And each $F[x]$ is infinite-dimensional over $F$. Therefore, $V$ is infinite-dimensional over $F$.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. But after some thought, I realize that if the linear transformation $T: V\to V$ is $T(v)=0$, then the $F[x]$-module is just the $F$-module, which is still nonzero and free, yet it is finite dimensional.

Comment: But there is no $T$ in the problem that you mentioned your question and there is no $T$ in my answer. The problem is simply “Show that any nonzero free $F[x]$-module $V$  is an infinite dimensional vector space over $F$.”

Comment: That was my fault-I have added some details to the post just now. I think the issue here is that "Therefore, $V$ is infinite-dimensional over $F$" can't be justified if we are to write it out rigorously, and that's precisely because we do not really know how $T$ behaves.

Comment: But what is that $T$ that you keep mentioning? We have that $V$ is a free $F[x]$-module. There is no $T$ in the definition of free $F[x]$-module. And then you claimed (correctly) that $V$ is a direct sum of copies of $F[x]$. That's all that I have used. And, again, where is that $T$?

Comment: A $F[x]$-module, by definition, must be associated with a linear transformation $T: V\to V$, because only then the action of $x$ on each $v\in V$ can be defined. It's like when we say two structures are isomorphic, we might not mention the isomorphism explicitly (which is a bijective function), but that is included in the definition.

Comment: For every commutative ring $R$, you can define the concept of [$R$-module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)) without any reference to such a map. Are you asserting that the rings of the form $F[x]$ are somehow an exception?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145747/discussion-between-dick-grayson-and-another-user).

Comment: The $F[x]$ module structure where multiplication by $x$ acts like the zero linear transformation is not a free $F[x]$ module structure.

Answer (score 1):

An $F[x]$-module is an abelian group $V$ with a group homomorphism
$$\varphi:\ F[x]\ \longrightarrow\ \operatorname{End}_{\Bbb{Z}}V.$$
If such a module is free and nonzero then $\varphi$ is injective, so $\operatorname{End}_{\Bbb{Z}}V$ is infinite dimensional over $F$. Then $V$ itself is also infinite dimensional over $F$.

Comment: Your answer involves machinery that I am not familiar with, but I still appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I finally dug myself out of the hole-I realize  that an $F[x]$-module is also an $F$-vector space, and an $F[x]$-module isomorphism is also an $F$-vector space isomorphism. The following is just a formalization of @Another User's answer.

Since $V$ is free, there exists $B=\{v_1, v_2,\dots\}$ such that each $v\in V$ can be written uniquely as a linear combination of elements in $B$ with coefficients in $F[x]$. Thus $V=N_1\oplus N_2\oplus\dots$, where $N_i=\{f(x)v_i|f(x)\in F[x]\}$. Obviously, the $F[x]$-submodule $N_1\subseteq V$ is $F[x]$-isomorphic to $F[x]$ via $\varphi: f(x)v_1\mapsto f(x)$, since $V$ is free implies each submodule is free. **Note that $\mathbf{\varphi}$ is also an $\mathbf{F}$-isomorphism when $\mathbf{N_1}$ and $\mathbf{F[x]}$ are viewed as $\mathbf{F}$-vector spaces**. Hence the **$\mathbf{F}$-vector space** $N_1$ is $F$-isomorphic to the **$\mathbf{F}$-vector space** $F[x]$, and the latter is infinite dimensional over $F$. Since $N_1$ is a $F$-subspace of $V$, it follows that $V$ is also infinite dimensional over $F$.

Comment: Why is the map $\varphi:\ f(x)v_1\ \mapsto\ f(x)$ an isomorphism? You state that this is obvious, but this requires that $N_1$ is free over $F[x]$ and nonzero, which you don't mention.

Comment: @Servaes Indeed, otherwise injectiveness would not be certain-thank you for pointing that out!